# How can I achieve the same without having the onclick = "showHide (this) in the html, but in jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, click

I want to put this function that is in the html:

onclick="showHide(this)"

but by jquery

https://codepen.io/ygovi/pen/jOWgMGq

HTML:

```
<div id="div" class="options" onclick="showHide(this)">This is the button.</div>
<div id="divcontent" class="showHide">This is a div to hide and show.</div>
<div id="div2" class="options" onclick="showHide(this)">This is the button.</div>
<div id="divcontent2" class="showHide">This is a div to hide and show.</div>
<div id="div3" class="options" onclick="showHide(this)">This is the button.</div>
<div id="divcontent3" class="showHide">This is a div to hide and show.</div>
```

JQUERY JQ:

```
$('.showHide').hide(); 

function showHide(btnxxx) {
  $(btnxxx).next(".showHide").toggle().siblings(".showHide").hide();
}
```

:( please help

you must retain the behavior:
-When I click on the first div with the options class, the corresponding .showHide div is displayed and any other div .showHide that has been opened before is hidden

-And when I click the div of the options class again, the corresponding .showHide div is hidden

https://codepen.io/ygovi/pen/jOWgMGq

Comment: Step one, review https://api.jquery.com/on and learn how to create event bindings.

Comment: @ygovi .Explain the problem clearly

Answer (score 1):

Jquery approach :
`$('.options').click(function(){ $(this).next(".showHide").toggle(); });`

and by removing `.siblings(".showHide").hide()` other showhide class will be as it is...

```js
$('.showHide').toggle(); 
$('.options').click(function(){
 $(this).next(".showHide").toggle();
});
/*function showHide(btnxxx) {
  $(btnxxx).next(".showHide").toggle();
}*/
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js
"></script>
<div id="div" class="options" >This is the button.</div>
<div id="divcontent" class="showHide">This is a div to hide and show.</div>
<div id="div2" class="options" >This is the button.</div>
<div id="divcontent2" class="showHide">This is a div to hide and show.</div>
<div id="div3" class="options" >This is the button.</div>
<div id="divcontent3" class="showHide">This is a div to hide and show.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63196947/how-can-i-achieve-the-same-without-having-the-onclick-showhide-this-in-the/63197544?noredirect=1#comment111756459_63197544) is due to `siblings()` function. Siblings are supposed to be nested in same wrapper.

```js
$('.mi_cuenta_opciones--detalles').hide();

$('.mi_cuenta_opciones--iconos').click(function() {
  $(this).next(".mi_cuenta_opciones--detalles").toggle().closest('tr').siblings('tr').find('.mi_cuenta_opciones--detalles').hide();
});
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.mi_cuenta_opciones {
  position: relative;
}

.mi_cuenta_opciones--iconos {
  padding-left: 20px;
  color: #000;
}

.mi_cuenta_opciones--detalles {
  width: 144px;
  height: auto;
  border: 0.5px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #fff;
  /* position: absolute; */
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  left: 60px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Pedido1</td>
    <td>
      <div class="mi_cuenta_opciones">
        <div class="mi_cuenta_opciones--iconos"> Opciones </div>
        <div class="mi_cuenta_opciones--detalles">
          <div class="mi_cuenta_opciones--ver">
            <a href="/user/203403/orders/1755021">Ver</a>
          </div>
          <div class="mi_cuenta_opciones--informar">
            <a class="informar_pago" href="/b2b_order/orders/inform_payment/1755021" alt="Informar Pago del pedido">Informar Pago</a>
          </div>
          <div class="mi_cuenta_opciones--cancelar">
            <a class="cancelar_pedido" href="/b2b_order/orders/cancel/1755021" alt="Cancelar Pedido">Cancelar</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Pedido2</td>
    <td>
      <div class="mi_cuenta_opciones">
        <div class="mi_cuenta_opciones--iconos"> Opciones </div>
        <div class="mi_cuenta_opciones--detalles">
          <div class="mi_cuenta_opciones--ver">
            <a href="/user/203403/orders/1755021">Ver</a>
          </div>
          <div class="mi_cuenta_opciones--informar">
            <a class="informar_pago" href="/b2b_order/orders/inform_payment/1755021" alt="Informar Pago del pedido">Informar Pago</a>
          </div>
          <div class="mi_cuenta_opciones--cancelar">
            <a class="cancelar_pedido" href="/b2b_order/orders/cancel/1755021" alt="Cancelar Pedido">Cancelar</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Pedido3</td>
    <td>
      <div class="mi_cuenta_opciones">
        <div class="mi_cuenta_opciones--iconos"> Opciones </div>
        <div class="mi_cuenta_opciones--detalles">
          <div class="mi_cuenta_opciones--ver">
            <a href="/user/203403/orders/1755021">Ver</a>
          </div>
          <div class="mi_cuenta_opciones--informar">
            <a class="informar_pago" href="/b2b_order/orders/inform_payment/1755021" alt="Informar Pago del pedido">Informar Pago</a>
          </div>
          <div class="mi_cuenta_opciones--cancelar">
            <a class="cancelar_pedido" href="/b2b_order/orders/cancel/1755021" alt="Cancelar Pedido">Cancelar</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

```js
$('.showHide').hide();
$('.options').click(function() {
  $(this).next('.showHide').toggle().siblings('.showHide').hide();
});
```

```html
<div id="div" class="options">This is the button.</div>
<div id="divcontent" class="showHide">This is a div to hide and show.</div>
<div id="div2" class="options">This is the button.</div>
<div id="divcontent2" class="showHide">This is a div to hide and show.</div>
<div id="div3" class="options">This is the button.</div>
<div id="divcontent3" class="showHide">This is a div to hide and show.</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: hello, this worked!, but when I try to pass it to another code it doesn't come out as in the example I put :( I don't know why. I leave the code here in case you can help me codepen.io/ygovi/pen/GRobpbe I really don't understand why it works in the example and in this code I don't

Comment: Please attach more html code then. I think jQuery couldn't select the DOM properly. Or you can just debug whether `click` event is triggering or not using alert or console log. And if it passes debug what returns `$(this)` value by `console.log($(this))`.

Comment: the code is here:
https://codepen.io/ygovi/pen/GRobpbe
(does not let me paste it in the comment because it exceeds the limit of letters)

Comment: Please include the code in Question, not in comment. I've solved it, I'll update my answer after your changes.